# Delphi ISAPI performance vs native server

Tags: delphi, web-applications, isapi

I have to make a public facing web application that does dynamic pages, sessions and serving documents. My main concerns are scalability, performance (around 1000 users/hour) and security.

I have looked at ISAPI extensions(IIS) and native servers. In terms of performance and scalability are ISAPI extensions better than native servers?

If developing a native server, what are good frameworks? Would something like realthinclient be worth it for the money?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What Web Application Framework for Delphi is recommended?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793112/what-web-application-framework-for-delphi-is-recommended)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

ISAPI works as a native extension to IIS and so long as your ISAPI dll is well constructed, performance should be the same or better than if you constructed your own proprietary web server. I would recommend creating an ISAPI extension to IIS rather than a separate web server - you get a lot of benefits from IIS (its threading model, application pools, etc), especially version 7 and later.

Comment: +1 Delphi has good and proven ISAPI support since (at least) Delphi 4. Altough we added a bunch of patches to the VCL code in the meantime to improve it even more, what you get right OOTB is a good starting point. Creating a web server from scratch would be a huge mountain of unnecessary work (let alone security considerations) to even get close to what you get with IIS and an ISAPI extension.